# Making part of the screen a scrollable image with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to get a part of the screen a scrollable image, so it will fit in the screen without ruining the image ratio (referring to notebook.jpg in the code). I saw some comments that suggested using ScrollView, but I couldn't really figure out how to add it to the existing class I already have (I mean as a second class in addition to NotebookScreen, so NotebookScreen will be able to use it).
Would really appreciate some help :)

Python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

GUI = Builder.load_file('style.kv')
# Window.size = (2224, 1668)


class NotebookScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.rows = 1
        super(NotebookScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return NotebookScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

kivy code:

```
<NotebookScreen>
    FloatLayout:
        rows: 2
        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .05
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            id: tool_bar
            cols: 1
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            id: notebook_grid
            size_hint: 1, .95
            pos_hint: {"top": .95, "left": 0}
            cols: 1
            Image:
                id: notebook_image
                source: 'images/notebook.jpg'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                pos: self.pos
                size_hint: 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example of how you could do that. I simply used a Label's canvas to draw the image. I added the label to the scrollview and added scrollview along with another label to show you that you don't need to have the entire screen for your scrolling part. I only used PIL to get the size of the image, because I wanted to make sure that your window is smaller than the image you want to scroll. I hope it helps you with your approach.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from PIL import Image


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        img = Image.open("path/to/your/image/dummy.jpg")

        Window.size = (img.size[0]*0.8, img.size[1]*1.2)
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint=(None, None), size=Window.size)

        lbl = Label(text="This is your picture!", size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height*0.5))
        layout.add_widget(lbl)

        sv = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height*0.5))
        img_box = Label(size_hint=(None, None), size=img.size)
        with img_box.canvas:
            Rectangle(source="path/to/your/image/dummy.jpg", size=img.size)

        sv.add_widget(img_box)
        layout.add_widget(sv)

        return layout

MyApp().run()
```

**[EDIT]**

Here is basically the same thing I made at first, but with some outsourcing to a kv string. I hope this is now, what you are looking for.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from PIL import Image

kv = """
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<MyImageView>:

    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: Window.size

    Label:
        text: "This is your picture!"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: Window.width, Window.height * .5
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: Window.width, Window.height * .5
        Label:
            id: img_box
            size_hint: None, None
            size: root.img.size
            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    source: root.img_path
                    size: root.img.size
"""

class MyImageView(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, img_path, **kwargs):
        self.img_path = img_path
        self.img = Image.open(self.img_path)
        Window.size = (self.img.size[0] * 0.8, self.img.size[1] * 1.2)
        super(MyImageView, self).__init__(**kwargs)



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        layout = MyImageView("Path/to/your/image.png")


        return layout

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: That's awesome, but I need to know how to do that in a kv format, as this is only a small part of what I'm trying to do.
Do you happen to know how to do that?

Comment: Of course you can outsource some stuff of it to your kv file, but for the PIL part you need a python declaration anyway. I would create a class inheriting a layout, that takes the picture path as an attribute. That way, you can reuse it whenever you want.

Comment: @amit yakovian : I added an kv example to my initial post.

Comment: Mark it as accepted answer please if it is what you are looking for.